# You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ',,,)' at line 1

Tags: php, mysql, sql

so I am working with a database and just got this error code:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ',,,)' at line 1

I searched on here and noticed that a lot of people have had the same problem, but I could not figure out exactly what I needed to change in my particular case.

EDIT: Sorry, I put in the wrong version at first. Fixed now.

The .php-file where I get this error code:

```
<?PHP
    require_once("base.php");
    $first = $_REQUEST["First"];
    $second  = $_REQUEST["Second"];
    $third = $_REQUEST["Third"];
    $fourth = $_REQUEST["Fourth"];
    $fifth = $_REQUEST["Fifth"];


    $SQL="insert into batch(first,second,third,fourth,fifth)

 values($first,$second,$third,$fourth,$fifth);";
    mysql_query($SQL)or die(mysql_error());
    header("location:12345.php");
?>
```

What is the issue here?

Comment: The values of `$first`, `$second`, `$third`, `$fourth` and `$fifth` aren't defined anywhere in your code, so what do you expect? Did you mean to use `$hemma`, `$borta`, `$arena`, `$ansvarigID` and `$publiksiffror`?

Comment: And you'd better pray that no nasty people ever visit your site, because... like... [Little Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: *`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`* - Of course. Don't treat strings like `int`s.

Comment: " check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax"  Says it all.

Comment: Learn to use MySQLi or PDO (not the deprecated, old MySQL interface); and learn to use parameterised statements so you don't need to remember to escape your data or quote your sting values

Comment: You also didn't put space where its needed but did where it isn't.

Comment: You are not only using wrong variables here, you are also not seperating them correctly in your query. It's `$SQL="insert into matcher(first,second,third,fourth,fifth)values('$first','$second','$third','$fourth','$fifth');";` further, be smart and escape your variables as well, plus use `mysqli` or `pdo`.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 4):

```
values($first,$second,$third,$fourth,$fifth);";
```

Should be

```
values('$first','$second','$third','$fourth','$fifth');";
```

However the single quote depends on the datatype. See the documentation.

Also  you may want to look into php's compiled sql statements - they'll help to prevent sql injection attacks;

Comment: That is an entirely different issue. For help on that you'll need to post the structure of the matcher table and the lag table (I guess that is their names).  Or and even better - create a sql fiddle - that will help us help you a great deal